# 3 Auto-Refreshing Divs on a page using JQuery but one of them doesn't work?

Tags: php, jquery

I have three divs on my page and each one is auto-refreshed using JQuery, here's the HTML:

```
<div id="photo">
    <?php require("image.php"); ?>
</div>

<div id="right-bar">
    <div id="facebook"> <?php require("graph.php"); ?></div>
</div>

<div id="bottom-bar">
    <?php require("twitter.php"); ?>
</div>
```

Here is the JQuery:

```
var imagecacheData;
var imagedata = $('#photo').html();
var imageauto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: 'image.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: imagedata,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(imagedata) {
            if (imagedata !== imagecacheData){
                //data has changed (or it's the first call), save new cache data and update div
                imagecacheData = imagedata;
                $('#photo').fadeOut("slow").html(imagedata).fadeIn("slow");
            }           
        }
    })
}, 60000); // check every minute

var cacheData;
var data = $('#facebook').html();
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: 'graph.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) {
            if (data !== cacheData){
                //data has changed (or it's the first call), save new cache data and update div
                cacheData = data;
                $('#facebook').fadeOut("slow").html(data).fadeIn("slow");
            }           
        }
    })
}, 30000); // check every 30 seconds

var twittercacheData;
var twitterdata = $('#bottom-bar').html();
var twitterauto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: 'twitter.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: twitterdata,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(twitterdata) {
            if (twitterdata !== twittercacheData){
                //data has changed (or it's the first call), save new cache data and update div
                twittercacheData = twitterdata;
                $('#bottom-bar').fadeOut("slow").html(twitterdata).fadeIn("slow");
            }           
        }
    })
}, 60000); // check every minute - reasonable considering time it takes 5 tweets to scroll across
```

As you can see, all of them are pretty much the same thing but the twitter section doesn't auto-refresh at all.

Also, as you can see I am trying to only get the page to do the fade out/ fade in if the response is actually different but it seems to be doing it anyway - any ideas as to why this is?

Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: Have you looked at the response from the twitter.php in firebug ?

Comment: that's the thing, firebug wasn't reporting any errors at all. I think I may have fixed it and the answer might have been as simple as signing in to Facebook (I wasn't signed in so the Facebook section wasn't working but just offering a link to sign in and as soon as I did it started working fine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out it the problem was facebook wasn't signed in.

Soon as that was done it was fixed.